# Image not showing up in my UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, nsurl

My images not showing up in my UICollectionView. I'm not sure what is the mistake. Below is my code.

MyCollectionView.swift

```
/** -- **/

    overide func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
            let event = events[indexPath.row]

            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "blabla_iPad@2x")

            return cell

        }

/** -- **/
```

MyCollectionViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 16, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

Even I'm using localPath, it's still not working.

```
/*
    /Users/MNurdin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B30917DD-1C57-430F-9ACF-6526B226CF15/data/Containers/Data/Application/35ACB17A-4C25-4A49-BE3D-04AA51F36CC0/tmp/jreGfApABajWPCnkfPBh.jpg
*/

cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath:localPath)!)!)
```

Comment: is it possible if I'm using programmatic way?

Comment: try typing the extension of image too for example blabla_iPad.png or blabla_iPad.jpg or whatever the extension is.

Comment: Is your MyCollectionViewCell created with a xib file? Try to create imageView in awakeFromNib method if you create with a xib file. Otherwise, try to create imageView in initWithCoder: too

Comment: No xib file. Just Main.Storyboard.

Comment: did your cell really appear? Did you try to set a backgroudnColor? How does your asset look like? why did you putt @2x in the name? Is its also the name of the asset or is it without @2x?

Comment: init with frame is maybe not called. only with aDecoder. so putt the imageView creation in the awakeFromNib function or prepare for reuse

Comment: Can you share any sample project? @Dato'MohammadNurdin

Comment: could it be UIImage is returning nil? have something like if let image = UIImage(named:"")

Comment: adding a background colour , did that reflect on your cell?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I'm afraid not, but I try to create a dummy project.

Comment: @BjörnRo Yes, i put exactly same with filename. I already change the background colour, still not showing up.

Comment: did you put a debug point into the init functions? Is there really a cell when dequeuing?

Comment: yes, it shows 1 record in this function.

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        println(items.count)
        return items.count
    }

Comment: Are you able to set the image to an UIImageView in a nib file(from the inspector)?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin then you don't have image named "blabla_iPad@2x" in images assets, where do you fetch it from if not stored image?

Comment: if setting the background shows nothing, than the cell is not shown.... i mean you did set backhroundcolor from the contentView and nothing appears? Check your itemSize in your collectionFlowLayout. If not set, than set it. For tests its enough to use 100x100

Answer (score 0):

```
 var imageView: UIImageView!
```

this should be an IBOutlet.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

And connect it to your storyboard.

Comment: hä?he is adding it as subview

Comment: yes he does, but using IBOutlets are a much cleaner solution. Also, if he would do so, i suspect he's problem would be resolved.

Comment: not really. Its added as Subview, the frame ist set. so it should appear

Comment: I will get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)  if i'm using this solution.

Comment: Make sure, that you are connecting the IBOutlet to your view. Check here how to: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html

Comment: I know how to connect the IBOutlet. But i want make it subview.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite the head scratcher. I don't know exactly whats wrong here, but here are a few tips i try myself to find whats happening

After:

cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "blabla_iPad@2x")

```
print(cell.imageView?.image.bounds.size)
cell.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
cell.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
```

u will see one of these things now:
1. same as before, this means u r drawing your image outside the cell. try changing the frame.
2. black bordered empty square: means something is wrong with your image
3. the frame printed has zero size. Assign the imageView frame equal to the bounds of the image.

Comment: I will try your solution.

Comment: what is the value of the frame? i.e. the print box output?

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure iamge is in Xcassets or in the top bundle.Save your image as "ImageName~ipad.png". It is just an identifier to ios to use this image on i-Pad. Put the image in Xcassets. Everything will work fine then.
- And also put some log message in your custom cell class initializer to check the control flow,whether something is wrong with your custom class.
- Have you registered your custom class to be used with this cell identifier in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are loading your cell from your storyboard. When loading from storyboards, the init(frame: CGRect) method in your MyCollectionViewCell class won't get called, which means your code to add your custom UIImageView to the cell's contentView never gets called too.

Hence, the problem isn't to do with the image not loading into the UIImageView, but is more to do with the entire UIImageView not getting added into the cell at all.

Try moving that to the awakeFromNib() instead

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Only happened on xib files I opened after switching to Swift 3. I disabled Clip To Bounds on any UIImageView in the xib and I can see the images again, but now my cornerRadius settings don't work.

Also had an issue when setting cornerRadius based on view size in awakeFromNib because xib views default with a frame size of (1000,1000).